# Use Exiftools to add a tag with spaces and special characters to an image file

Tags: exif, mapillary

When I try to upload an image to Mapillary using it's web page based uploader and it's executable I get 
[image]
EXIF Time issue.

When I compare a file that uploads correctly and the issue jpg file in EXIFTOOLS I see that it doesn't have Create Date, Date/Time Original and Modify Date. There are lots of other fields as well but these are the only ones dealing with time.

[image]

When I try to use

```
'.\exiftool(-k).exe' -"Date/Time Original"="2019:10:27 18:14:10.5" Photo_2019_Jul_12_13_38_40_019.jpg
```

It doesn't let me add the tag (I assume) because it has a '/' in it. It also doesn't allow "Create Date" for example.

How can I create a tag with these?

Some sample files are in https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QCQdSvdk0RygfCqqRWaOj-IzBbj17gax?usp=sharing

This is just to see if adding this will allow it to work in Mapillary but if anyone has an alternative solution to fix these hundreds of thousands of images that I have to upload it will be fine.

Comment: I just want to move this to Stackoverflow - I flagged it myself to try and move it.